# How to judge whether two addresses are in same page or not in Windows?

Tags: windows

Specifically, if at different time, I read the addresses pointed by the ESP register(containing the stack top address), how to judge the two addresses are in the same page or not? I believe these addresses are physical addresses rather than virtual addresses,right?The two readings might come from different processes. How does Windows do the page allocation?

Added:maybe I got it. So if we use a 4KB page, does that mean the addresses from 0x....XXXX0000 to 0x....XXXX1000 are in the same page?

Comment: What is the problem you are having where you think detecting pointers on the same page will solve it?

Comment: @RaymondChen  It's a homework assignment actually. The basic idea is that if the two stacks are in the same page, then probably the two threads are the same one. This is used to detect call-ret pairs:>

Comment: To detect if two threads are the same, use GetCurrentThreadId on the two threads. Or GetCurrentFiber if you also need to handle fibers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got it almost right. The idea is sound, but the range would be `0x????0000` to `0x????0FFF`. If you were to use `DWORD_PTR` or `ULONG_PTR` you could also mask out the lower 12bit `(ptr & 0xFFF)` and compare the two pointer values you got. `ULONG_PTR` and `DWORD_PTR` should work both on x64 and x86.

Keep in mind that your system could be using huge pages. So make sure to use [`GetNativeSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx) and/or `GetSystemInfo` respectively. You are looking for the value of `dwAllocationGranularity` in the `SYSTEM_INFO` structure.

All of this is true within the same process memory space *only*.

Concerning the question about physical addresses: **no**, I repeat **no**, user mode process gets to see actual physical addresses unless some driver or the kernel itself screws up.

Assuming you are talking about addresses in DLLs you cannot make proper assumptions about shared pages starting with Vista and its ASLR feature.

Comment: @0xC0000022L  So you mean the ESP contains the virtual address of the stack top rather than physical address? Then this means it's impossible to find whether two processes' stacks are in the same page because they are in different memory space. It's only possible to find whether two threads' stacks are in the same page because they share the same memory space.Right?

Comment: Yes, it would be impossible from the user mode perspective to find that out. I'd say if you want to detect whether two threads are the same they have to be in the same process (unless they're system threads, but I doubt homework involves kernel mode questions) and have the same thread ID.